# How to get data back from video capture activity on Samsung tab?

Tags: android

I got some problems to get back data from video capture activity on a Samsung Galaxy tab.
I read that is a Samsung issue, but I need a way to do this.
The video file is correctly saved.

So, I call the activity:

```
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(path);
Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_FINISH_ON_COMPLETION, true);
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY,1);
context.startActivityForResult(i, 500);
```

In my onActivityResult() I get something only when I press BACK in the camera activity, and it is a RESULT_CANCELED result. I cannot get the RESULT_OK, I think because the Samsung video app does not returns.

I need to get the result intent. How?

Answer (score 1):

> The video file is correctly saved.

Can you open the video using the path,after press back button !?

Like(pseudoCode) :

```
onActivityResult
{
  if(video exist)
  { 
     open video
  }else
     show message error
```